# How Cn I pass parameter to a gulp task which is inturn called by a Gradle task

Tags: gradle, gulp, arguments

I have a Gradle task in my build.gradle which is calling a Gulp task:

```
task runProtractorRegression(type: Exec){
  executable "xvfb-run"
  args "gulp", "runEndtoEnd_headless" 
}
```

Gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('runEndtoEnd_headless', ['runEndtoEnd_headless:src']);
gulp.task('runEndtoEnd_headless:src', runEndtoEnd_headless);

function runEndtoEnd_headless (done) {
   var params = process.argv;
   var args = params.length > 3 ? [params[3]] : [];
   console.log("Parameter to Gulp task:runEndtoEnd_headless is:",args);
   gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.e2e,'./src/test/web/testScripts/Validations/*.js'))
.pipe($.protractor.protractor({
    configFile: 'runEndtoEnd_headless.conf.js',
    args: args
}))
}
```

I am able to run the gulp task by passing a parameter like this:

```
gulp runEndtoEnd_headless --params.login.argument=DEV
```

How can i pass the parameter mentioned above to my Gradle task: runProtractorRegression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args "gulp", "runEndtoEnd_headless", "--params.login.argument=DEV"
```

Just add arguments to your `args` line as comma separated strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply RaGe. Actually I wanted to run the gradle command through terminal window. I figured it out. 
In my build.gradle file I have:
args "gulp", "runEndtoEnd_headless", argument .
And in terminal window:
gradle runProtractorRegression -Pargument=--params.login.argument=ci

Comment: Hi, The parameter _'argument'_ to my gradle task as mentioned above will be passed dynamically by Jenkins workflow. However, _'argument'_ is not getting resolved when a **'gradle build'** happens. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: What is the error message? You should probably raise a new question.